# Python TextBox append text WITHOUT newline

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing blocks of text to a TextBox and the code appears to be deciding i want a newline every time i invoke Append().

I want "1" + "2" + "3" to appear as:

```
123
```

not:

```
1
2
3
```

See the attached code example

```
from guizero import App, TextBox, PushButton

def append():
    txtboxTest.value = '1'
    txtboxTest.append('2')
    txtboxTest.append('3')

app = App(title="Test")
txtboxTest = TextBox(app, width=300, height=3, multiline=True, scrollbar=True)
appendbutton = PushButton(app, command=append, text="Write Text")

app.display()
```

Comment: What happens if you try `txtboxTest.value = '%s2' % txtboxTest.value`? Can you add a digit that way? The `guizero` docs suggest a newline won't be appended, so I suspect trying another approach might help figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Same result. I should say i also tried `def append():
    txtboxTest.value = '1'
    txtboxTest.value = txtboxTest.value + '2'
    txtboxTest.value = txtboxTest.value + '3' ` It appears whether i use .value or.append() i get a newline

Comment: The HEAD code for the control is here: https://github.com/lawsie/guizero/blob/master/guizero/TextBox.py There's no mention of an `\n`. Are '1', '2', '3' strings you show examples, or are they the actual strings you're using?

Comment: They are examples but i get exactly the same behaviour in my real app

Comment: when using append(), modifying txtbox.value will invoke @value.setter, which causes a new line to be generated

Comment: Ok so that explains it but how can I achieve the desired results - i.e. no carriage return?